# display the post of particular category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display the post category name "futureblog". my code is below.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
            the_content('<span class="read_more">read more</span>');
        echo '</div>';
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i want display post only category name futureblog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is you want.

```
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(); $wp_query->query('showposts=5'.'&category_name=futureblog');

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
        echo '<div class="entry-content">';
            the_content('<span class="read_more">read more</span>');
        echo '</div>';
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array('category_name' =>'demo','posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); 
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
?>
<ul>
    <li>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```